# Mapbox Fragment inside another activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, mapbox-android

I'm trying to create an application that tracks a user's eyes while driving which will also show turn by turn navigation. There will be a camera preview on the same screen as the maps, similar to the image below, where the camera preview is in the top left and the maps is below

[image: activity_test.xml]

I have a MapBox activity working in a seperate file, MapsActivity.java. I want to run the Mapbox activity inside a fragment in an activty test.java which does the eye tracking.

I have looked at tutorials and online resources but cannot find out how to get it to work for my particular code. Apologies if this is a simple question, this is my first app.

**MapsActivity.java**

```
package com.example.drivesafely;

import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsListener;
import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager;
import com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.models.DirectionsResponse;
import com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.models.DirectionsRoute;
import com.mapbox.geojson.Feature;
import com.mapbox.geojson.Point;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationComponent;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.modes.CameraMode;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Style;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.SymbolLayer;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.sources.GeoJsonSource;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationLauncher;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationLauncherOptions;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.route.NavigationMapRoute;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.navigation.NavigationRoute;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.PropertyFactory.iconAllowOverlap;
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.PropertyFactory.iconIgnorePlacement;
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.PropertyFactory.iconImage;

// classes needed to initialize map
// classes needed to add the location component
// classes needed to add a marker
// classes to calculate a route
// classes needed to launch navigation UI


public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, MapboxMap.OnMapClickListener, PermissionsListener {
    // variables for adding location layer
    private MapView mapView;
    private MapboxMap mapboxMap;
    // variables for adding location layer
    private PermissionsManager permissionsManager;
    private LocationComponent locationComponent;
    // variables for calculating and drawing a route
    private DirectionsRoute currentRoute;
    private static final String TAG = "DirectionsActivity";
    private NavigationMapRoute navigationMapRoute;
    // variables needed to initialize navigation
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.access_token));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;
        mapboxMap.setStyle(getString(R.string.navigation_guidance_day), new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
            @Override
            public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                enableLocationComponent(style);

                addDestinationIconSymbolLayer(style);

                mapboxMap.addOnMapClickListener(MapsActivity.this);
                button = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        boolean simulateRoute = true;
                        NavigationLauncherOptions options = NavigationLauncherOptions.builder()
                                .directionsRoute(currentRoute)
                                .shouldSimulateRoute(simulateRoute)
                                .build();
// Call this method with Context from within an Activity
                        NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(MapsActivity.this, options);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private void addDestinationIconSymbolLayer(@NonNull Style loadedMapStyle) {
        loadedMapStyle.addImage("destination-icon-id",
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.mapbox_marker_icon_default));
        GeoJsonSource geoJsonSource = new GeoJsonSource("destination-source-id");
        loadedMapStyle.addSource(geoJsonSource);
        SymbolLayer destinationSymbolLayer = new SymbolLayer("destination-symbol-layer-id", "destination-source-id");
        destinationSymbolLayer.withProperties(
                iconImage("destination-icon-id"),
                iconAllowOverlap(true),
                iconIgnorePlacement(true)
        );
        loadedMapStyle.addLayer(destinationSymbolLayer);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings( {"MissingPermission"})
    @Override
    public boolean onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng point) {

        Point destinationPoint = Point.fromLngLat(point.getLongitude(), point.getLatitude());
        Point originPoint = Point.fromLngLat(locationComponent.getLastKnownLocation().getLongitude(),
                locationComponent.getLastKnownLocation().getLatitude());

        GeoJsonSource source = mapboxMap.getStyle().getSourceAs("destination-source-id");
        if (source != null) {
            source.setGeoJson(Feature.fromGeometry(destinationPoint));
        }

        getRoute(originPoint, destinationPoint);
        button.setEnabled(true);
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.mapboxBlue);
        return true;
    }

    private void getRoute(Point origin, Point destination) {
        NavigationRoute.builder(this)
                .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken())
                .origin(origin)
                .destination(destination)
                .build()
                .getRoute(new Callback<DirectionsResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Response<DirectionsResponse> response) {
// You can get the generic HTTP info about the response
                        Log.d(TAG, "Response code: " + response.code());
                        if (response.body() == null) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "No routes found, make sure you set the right user and access token.");
                            return;
                        } else if (response.body().routes().size() < 1) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "No routes found");
                            return;
                        }

                        currentRoute = response.body().routes().get(0);

// Draw the route on the map
                        if (navigationMapRoute != null) {
                            navigationMapRoute.removeRoute();
                        } else {
                            navigationMapRoute = new NavigationMapRoute(null, mapView, mapboxMap, R.style.NavigationMapRoute);
                        }
                        navigationMapRoute.addRoute(currentRoute);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Throwable throwable) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + throwable.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings( {"MissingPermission"})
    private void enableLocationComponent(@NonNull Style loadedMapStyle) {
// Check if permissions are enabled and if not request
        if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)) {
// Activate the MapboxMap LocationComponent to show user location
// Adding in LocationComponentOptions is also an optional parameter
            locationComponent = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent();
            locationComponent.activateLocationComponent(this, loadedMapStyle);
            locationComponent.setLocationComponentEnabled(true);
// Set the component's camera mode
            locationComponent.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING);
        } else {
            permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
            permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        permissionsManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    public void onExplanationNeeded(List<String> permissionsToExplain) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.user_location_permission_explanation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionResult(boolean granted) {
        if (granted) {
            enableLocationComponent(mapboxMap.getStyle());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.user_location_permission_not_granted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

**activity_maps**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLat="38.9098"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="-77.0295"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="12" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@color/mapboxGrayLight"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="Start navigation"
        android:textColor="@color/mapboxWhite"
        mapbox:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        mapbox:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_test.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:background="#fcfcfc"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    tools:context=".test">


    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="#f567"
        mapbox:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/preview"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLat="38.9098"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="-77.0295"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="12" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@color/mapboxGrayLight"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="Start navigation"
        android:textColor="@color/mapboxWhite"
        tools:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="#19b5fe"
            android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="#E0E0E0"
                android:text="@string/end" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="New ToggleButton"
                android:textColor="#ffff"
                android:textOff="@string/turn_preview_off"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Status: "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        </TableRow>


    </RelativeLayout>


    <com.example.drivesafely.CameraSourcePreview
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <com.example.drivesafely.GraphicOverlay
            android:id="@+id/faceOverlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </com.example.drivesafely.CameraSourcePreview>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to run `Activity` inside another `Activity`, in your case you can't run `MapsActivity` in your `TestActivity`. This is possible with some other solutions but the easiest one for you is to use `Fragments`. What you can do is to convert your `MakeActivity` to `Fragment` and then place it inside `TestActivity`. Learn how Fragments and Activities work in Android since you'll be using them a lot.

Here are some links to read:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html
- https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments

Answer (score 0):

You can put a Maps SDK for Android map fragment inside of your `TestActivity` or inside a separate fragment

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/support-map-fragment/

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/?search=fragment